# Force MatSnackBar to update UI after receiving data update

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

My application is making use of a MatSnackBar to display error information to the user based on the results of multiple API calls that are triggered with a button click.

Since the API calls can return from the backend at different times we need a way for the Snackbars data to be updated with new information as the API calls return. To do this the UI component in question has a reference to a SnackbarService, and when the API calls error the details of the response are pushed to the SnackbarService.

The SnackbarService itself has a record of all the errors that have been pushed from the UI `_snackbarData`, this information is pushed through a BehaviourSubject, which is provided to the snackbar through its config. When the UI component pushes the error information to the SnackbarService it is then pushed through the BehaviourSubject and the snackbar has an up to date list of all of the errors it needs to display.

This all works fine, if I put console logs in I can see exactly when the error details are being pushed to the snackbar and the snackbar receives them all properly.

The issue is that for some reason the snackbar refuses to display anymore than one error at a time, despite an *ngFor being used to display the data. If I close and reopen the snackbar, all of the errors are displayed as expected. However I want to keep the snackbar open and append data to it instead of closing and reopening each time there is a new error.

A strange side effect of this, and proof that the snackbar is receiving the error data properly, is that when the snackbar is clicked to dismiss, the second error appears briefly before the snackbar fades away.

Is there anyway I can force the UI of the snackbar to update on receiving new data?

UI Component

```
ngOnInit() {

this._genericErrorService.genericErrorSubject$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((errorDetails: ErrorDetails) => {
      this.syncingClasses = false;
      console.log("Pushed error");
      this._errorSnackbarService.pushErrorToSnackbar(errorDetails);
    });
}
```

SnackbarService

```
export class ErrorSnackbarService {

  private _snackbarData: ErrorDetails[];
  errorDetailsSubject: BehaviorSubject<ErrorDetails[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ErrorDetails[]>(this._snackbarData);

  constructor(private _snackbar: MatSnackBar) {
    this._snackbarData = [];
  }

  pushErrorToSnackbar(errorDetails: ErrorDetails) {
    this.appendSnackbarData(errorDetails);
    this.errorDetailsSubject.next(this._snackbarData);
    if(!this.isSnackbarActive()) {
      this._snackbar.dismiss();
      this.displaySnackbar();
    } else { //This else causes the errors to be displayed as expected, without it the snackbar doesn't update. 
      this._snackbar.dismiss();
      this.displaySnackbar();
    }
  }
}

  private displaySnackbar() {
    this._snackbar.openFromComponent(ErrorSnackbarComponent, {
      data: this.errorDetailsSubject,
      duration: 0,
    });

    this._snackbar._openedSnackBarRef.afterDismissed().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
      this.clearSnackbar();
    })
  }

  private appendSnackbarData(errorDetails: ErrorDetails) {
    this._snackbarData.push(errorDetails);
  }

  clearSnackbar() {
    this._snackbarData = [];
  }

  dismissSnackbar() {
    this._snackbar.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Snackbar Component

```
export class ErrorSnackbarComponent extends AbstractBaseComponent implements OnInit {

  private _errorList: ErrorDetails[];

  constructor(baseService: BaseService,
              private _matSnackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<ErrorSnackbarComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: BehaviorSubject<ErrorDetails[]>) {
    super(baseService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.subscribe(res => {
      console.log("errorList: ", res);
      this._errorList = res;


    })
  }

  dismiss() {
    this._matSnackBarRef.dismiss();
  }

}
```

Snackbar Template

```
<div (click)="dismiss()" class="pointer">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let error of _errorList">
      <div class="col-1 error-icon-container">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!isWarning(error.errorKey)" class="error-icon">cancel</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="isWarning(error.errorKey)" class="warning-icon">warning</mat-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="col-11 margin-auto">
      <span class="snackbar-text">
        {{ getTranslateKey("errors." + error.errorKey) | translate }}
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update an existing SnackBar component by saving the reference and then applying the value to the instance. For example, using Angular's SnackBar Pizza Example:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarRef} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

/**
 * @title Snack-bar with a custom component
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'snack-bar-component-example',
  templateUrl: 'snack-bar-component-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['snack-bar-component-example.css'],
})
export class SnackBarComponentExample implements OnInit {
  durationInSeconds = 50;
  currentSnackBar: MatSnackBarRef<PizzaPartyComponent>;

  constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval( () => {
      if (this.currentSnackBar) {
        this.currentSnackBar.instance.currentTime += 1
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  openSnackBar() {
    this.currentSnackBar = this._snackBar.openFromComponent(PizzaPartyComponent, {
      duration: this.durationInSeconds * 1000,
    });
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'snack-bar-component-example-snack',
  templateUrl: 'snack-bar-component-example-snack.html',
  styles: [`
    .example-pizza-party {
      color: hotpink;
    }
  `],
})
export class PizzaPartyComponent {
  currentTime = 0;
}
```

Working StackBlitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txcovs

The general idea is that when you open the component, you need to save that Snack Bar Reference and then apply any changes to that specific Reference.